# Javascript onload event not invoking

Tags: javascript, jsp, event-handling, dom-events

I am working on a simple application whereby users can select snowboarding programmes. They can only select a maximum of 3 programmes thus, the program checks a collection that stores the programmes and if it contains > 3 entries, then it should disable all the buttons available to the user. However the function doesn't seem like it's being invoked.I have tried with different event triggers such as onclick etc but to no avail. 
Any help is appreciated.

[image: Timetable view]

Javascript Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function restrictSelection(t) {

        var selectedButton = document.getElementById(t);
        var selectedLessonSize = document.getElementById("selectedLessonSize");
        if (selectedLessonSize.value > 3) { 
            alert("more than 3");
             selectedButton.disabled = true;  
         } else {
             selectedButton.disabled = false;
             alert("less than 3");
         }  
 }  

</script>
```

JSP ForEach Loop (iterates through a collection and displays available programmes):

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${lessonTimetable.lessons}">

    <form method="POST" action="chooseLesson">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${entry.key}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${entry.value.description}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${entry.value.date}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${entry.value.startTime}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${entry.value.endTime}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${entry.value.level}"/></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="lessonid" value="${entry.key}"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="selectedLessonSize" value="${lessonSelection.numChosen}"/>
                <input id="button${entry.key}" type="submit" value="select lesson" disabled="true" onload="restrictSelection(this)"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Only finishing external resource loading triggers `onload` event, elements like `body`, `img`, `iframe`etc.

Comment: hmm, I thought it was something to do with that

Answer (score 0):

try to change `<input id="button${entry.key}" type="submit" .....` 
to `<button id="button${entry.key}"  onclick="restrictSelection(this.id)">.....`

Comment: this will only trigger the event upon clicking on a button, I want to pass each button to the function's parameter, and invoke the function as soon as the page loads.